# Traversing and search with xpath

Tags: xpath

My code:

```
"/root/pharagraph/sentence[" + y + "]/sequence/word"
```

that is same like

```
"/root/pharagraph[1]/sentence[" + y + "]/sequence/word"
```

Problem is that I want something like:

```
"/root/pharagraph[*]/sentence[" + y + "]/sequence/word"
```

So my Xpath search the sentence y in first pharagraph but I want to search sentence y in all pharagraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your first XPath expression is the same as your hypothetical XPath (the 3rd XPath). If you get only the first matched element using the 1st XPath, then the problem is in the code that execute the XPath, not in the XPath it self. For example, since I came from .NET, this might happen when one is using the wrong [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of the correct [`SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute the XPath.